# When building a Calendar-like app, what is the best way to store future events in Postgres, in order to avoid issues with daylight savings time?

Tags: c#, angular, postgresql

I am building a Calendar-like app in Angular/.NET/Postgres stack.

Since I have the usecase of storing future events in db, and then showing them on the UI in a form of a calendar, what would be the best way to store timestamps?
The potential bug that is worrying me is what about when daylight savings time occurs.

For example, lets say that an event is scheduled today(2023/08/14 21:00:00) for 3 months in advance (2023/11/14 21:00:00) and the daylight savings time occurs somewhere in the middle (lets say 2023/10/22 21:00:00).

I was thinking of storing only UTC timestamps, but I have read that then it might be faulty when the daylight savings time occurs, because browsers will interpet it differently because of the changed offset, and that I am in danger of showing wrong times for the event to the user.

Second idea is to store UTC timestamp and "wall timestamp" (wall time, time on the clock) that would be in the user's timezone, would that resolve the daylight savings time problem?

I was thinking of storing only UTC timestamps, but I fear that UI/browser will interpret it differently because of the changed offset (daylight savings time).

Comment: Use the range type tstzrange: It fives you a start and end, you can add constraints, you can use indexes, and you can play with time zones. The database is using UTC already, no need to duplicate code and introduce new bugs. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure the browser will handle this for you.  Continue to use the UTC timestamp, and the datetime string you get back will likely be in ISO format.  If you pass that into `new Date(...)` in the browser (client-side), the user's timezone in the OS/browser should convert correctly, daylight savings or not.

Comment: You can't convert it to UTC if you don't know the offset of the date in the future.  So it would probely be better to store it in local time (maybe put the timezone (not offset) in a different column) or you could use a timezone library that can determine the offset of future dates to get the right UTC, but i'm not sure you gain much by storing it as UTC ...